# Cloudformation: How to make resources configurable as per user input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I was writing Cloudformation template for beanstalk when I faced this situation. I had below code in my template

```
 SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '80'
      ToPort: '80'
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ELBSecGroupForBeanStalk
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '22'
      ToPort: '22'
      CidrIp: !If
        - Range
        - !Ref AcessIPRange
        - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '22'
      ToPort: '22'
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !If
        - SecurityGroupRange
        - !Ref CustomeSecurityGroup
        - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
```

Now you can see I have hardcoded port 22 and 80 but how I can make them configurable.

suppose a user comes and want to add 4 ports or 6. I want to make configurable, so the same template can be used. I can make them parameterize but not getting a way to make configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way of achieving that with CloudFormation only. That would be a dynamic number of resources and this is not part of CF.

Your best options would be:

- Use a tool like [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) to dynamically generate the CloudFormation template that will be used (therefore with a dynamic number of ports)
- Use a [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) on your template instead of specifying the `SecurityGroupIngress`. The Lambda function would take the SecurityGroupId as a parameter, as well as the ports number. From there, you can call the AWS APIs (with NodeJS, Python or anything that works with Lambda) and add the ports that you want. Don't forget to also include code to update and delete the rules as you update your template.